# Unupgradable packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

I'm gonna walk you through my standard updating process, every time I log into my computer (Ubuntu 22.04) I open a command prompt and run:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

It's been working fine for almost 10 years, but since about 8 months or so it doesn't work any more. I get this prompt almost every time:

```
 The following packages have been kept back:
     the-packages that-have been-kept-back
```

I googled what to do and I found an answer that said to do a `dist-upgrade`, but when I did, I lost a bunch of my packages (most notably `gnome-utils` which messed up a lot of my UI). It took me a while to rectify, so now I just copy paste the packages that have been kept back and it works, but it feels wrong, I'm "manually" installing a bunch of random stuff.

I'm not super knowledgeable in package management, but does anyone recognize this problem and how to fix it? Thank you